# Django Template - List not rendering properly

Tags: javascript, python, django, python-3.x, django-templates

I have the following list which is sent to django template using render function: `["9.8 m/s", "9.9 m/s", "1.0 m/s"]`.

When the list is printed in javascript function, it shows as: `[&quot;9.8 m/s&quot;, &quot;9.9 m/s&quot;, &quot;1.0 m/s&quot;]`

I have used the following to print the list: `console.log("{{ options }}");` in javascript function.

I have tried iterating over as

```
{% for option in options %}
    console.log("{{ option }}");
{% endfor %}
```

The above code displays single characters as opposed to printing list elements.
Also tried **JSON.parse** and **JSON.stringify** functions in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template engine will HTML *escape* the strings it renders. You can avoid that with the [**`|safe`** template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#safe):

```
var options = {{ option|safe }};

for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    console.log(options[i]);
}
```

Comment: `var options = JSON.parse(["9.8 m/s", "9.9 m/s", "1.0 m/s"]);` It rendered this with your solution, still getting: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 4. Removed the characters **&quot;**, but still getting error. Am i missing something?

Comment: @Hatim: ah yes, you do not need `JSON.parse`, since it is a JSON blob that is yielded to the response.